# Javascript find increase and decrease percentage of two numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find if the percentage has increased or decreased from a number to the other one. But the decrease is not working well.

```js
var current = 400;
var june = 500;

var percentchange = june / current * 100.0;

if(june > current) {
    var percentchange = june / current * 100.0;
    console.log('-' + percentchange)
  } else {
    console.log(percentchange)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the [percent change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference#Percentage_change), you could take the delta (new value minus old value) in relation to the old value times 100.

```js
const 
    percentChange = (v1, v2) => (v2 - v1) / v1 * 100,
    current = 400,
    june = 500,
    percent = percentChange(june, current);

console.log(percent);
```

Comment: I changed `current` with 300 and `june` with 512 so techincally it should be an increase but instead it shows a decrease.

Comment: it depends on the base of the calculation. in my example, `june` is the base and `current` is the relative value.